# how to pass multiple values to the modal upon clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

Here I want to display some data on the modal upon clicking a button. Right now nothing happens when clicking a button. Neither it throws error nor it displays modal and data. What might be wrong here.

```
if(details[i].taskmaster_id && details[i].events.length){
                     var id = details[i].taskmaster_id
                     var cleaner = details[i].tm_name
                     var name = details[i].name
                     var checkin = details[i].events[j].check_in
                     var checkout = details[i].events[j].check_out
                      # this displays right data in console
                     console.log(id)
                     console.log(name)
                    messageCleaner.innerHTML='<button class="btn btn-msg-cleaner btn-sm" id="msg" data-id='+id+' data-cleaner='+cleaner+' data-name='+name+' data-checkin='+checkin+' data-checkout='+checkout+' >Message to Cleaner</button>';
                        //appending Message to Cleaner button
                        headerContentJustify.appendChild(messageCleaner);
                    }

$('#msg').on('click', function(e){
const { id, name, cleaner, checkin, checkout  } = e.target.dataset;
$("#sendmessagetocleaner").modal('show')
$('#sendmessagetocleaner').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#cleaner_id").val(id)
        $("#cleaner_name").val(cleaner)
        $("#sub").val(`${name}${checkin}${checkout}`)
    })

});
```

modal

```
<inputname="cleaner" id="cleaner_id">
<input type="text" id="cleaner_name" name="subject" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="subject" id="sub" class="form-control">
```

Comment: does your button event gets called or not when you click it? . Because , here you are generating your `btn` ie :`msg` dynamically so your event should look like `$(document).on('click','#msg', function(e){..` .Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) post

Comment: I got one problem here. For example If the value of `var name` has two words then while displaying here `$("#cleaner_name").val(name)` it only displays the first word and removes the word after space . Why is that happening @Swati ?